# A Simpler Solution to an Optimization Problem.

Tags: derivatives, optimization

**The Problem:**
[image: The Problem Statement]

**My Solution:**
Let me model this situation in the first quadrant of the $x$-$y$ plane. Let us take the line $y=mx+c$ as the ladder (moving in the first quadrant). This is how the ladder moving in the corridor looks:

[image: The motion of the ladder]

The $y$-intercept of the line is $c$ and the $x$-intercept is $\left(-\frac{c}{m}\right)$. Since the ladder is moving in the first quadrant, we have
$$
m<0 \text{ and } c>0
$$
Let $L$ be the length of the ladder. Then,
$$
L^2=c^2+\left(\frac{c}{m}\right)^2
$$

or

$$
c=-\frac{mL}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} \text{ (Negative sign because m<0)}
$$

and therefore, the equation of the ladder becomes
$$
y=mx-\frac{mL}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$

As the ladder is transported through the corridor, the distance between the ladder and the corner becomes smaller up to a minimum and then start increasing again. The goal here is to choose $L$ such that the ladder just touches the corner as it clears the corridor. This $L$ would be the max length of the ladder.

Let the gap along the $y$-direction between the corner and the ladder be $s$. Let the co-ordinates of the corner be $(a,b)$. Then,
$$
s=b-ma+\frac{mL}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$

For a given ladder, this distance hits  a minimum value for a certain value of $m$. Let's find that out
$$
\frac{ds}{dm}=-a+\frac{L}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}-\frac{Lm^2}{(1+m^2)^\frac{3}{2}}=0
$$

Solving which we obtain the value of $m$ which makes $s$ hit its minimum value
$$
m=-\left\{\left(\frac{L}{a}\right)^\frac{2}{3}-1\right\}^\frac{1}{2} \text{ (Negative because m<0)}
$$

Therefore,
$$
s_{\text{min}}=b+a\left\{\left(\frac{L}{a}\right)^\frac{2}{3}-1\right\}^\frac{1}{2}+L\left\{1-\left(\frac{a}{L}\right)^\frac{2}{3}\right\}
$$

The value of $s_{\text{min}}$ in the case of this problem is zero. Therefore, solving the above equation, we get
$$
L=a\left\{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^\frac{2}{3}+1\right\}^\frac{3}{2}=\left(b^\frac{2}{3}+a^\frac{2}{3}\right)^\frac{3}{2}
$$

Plugging, $a=8$ and $b=6$ as asked in the question we get
$$
L=19.7313 \approx 20 \text{ feet}
$$

Is this correct? If yes, can we make an easier model to solve this problem? (Only in the context of calculus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation of the sliding ladder is alright. The answer given here cannot get any simpler. There is corner contact only at a single instant.

Easier modeling is by using symbols with trig. Start with making a sketch of the corner.

$$ \text{For easy trig typing using shorthand}\;$$
$$ s = \sin \phi, c = \cos \phi \text{, slant ladder length =  } $$

$$ L=\frac {b}{s}+ \frac{a}{c} \tag 1 $$

Differentiate with respect to $\phi$

$$ \frac{-bc}{s^2}+\frac{as}{c^2}=0 \tag2 $$

Simplify to find $\tan \phi$

$$ \frac{s}{c}=\tan \phi= {\left( \frac {b}{a}\right)}^ {\frac13} \tag 3$$

[image]

Construct right triangle with Pythagorean thm ( even if the dimension does not tally to linear dimension )  resolving $(s,c)$ to conveniently plug their values into (1) and then simplify

$$ L={\left(   a^{\frac23}+ b^{\frac23}\right)}^ {\frac32} \tag 4 $$

Actually it is an Astroid envelope of the sliding ladder having equation

$$ x^{\frac23}+ y^{\frac23}= L^{\frac23}$$

on to which you juxtaposed a sharp corner from right  side.

The 3 lines ( two blue,one red) *have the same length* 19.7313 units. Only the red line touches the corner $(8.6)$ . The blue lines do not touch the corner, there is considerable gap/clearance.

[image]

Now plug in numerical values for symbols

$$a=6,\; b=8,\;L \approx 19.7313 \;ft, \; \phi= 42.2568^{\circ}; \tag 5 $$

If corridor widths are changed you know what to do.

Comment: This model assumes the ladder to be in contact with the corner at all times. But the ladder touches the corner only momentarily.

Comment: Not at all. The model does not assume contact with corner always but assumes  contact *only with the wall and floor* along which the ladder slides. This is ensured in the formulation. Your misconception can be hopefully cleared by sketch just now added. To drive home this point I mentioned already about the Astroid that touches the corner at a single point.  All other positions of the ladder keeps it clear from re-entrant corner without any contact or interference as shown.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is correct. Note that the question says to round $\color{red}{down}$ to the nearest foot.

---

Consider

[image]

You have two right-angled triangles, and they share the same angle $\theta$ since the horizontal black and green lines are parallel. Then you can shown that the length of the ladder is given by

$$L(\theta)=\frac{6}{\sin(\theta)}+\frac{8}{\cos(\theta)}$$

for $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then

$$L'(\theta)=0\implies \tan^3(\theta)=\frac{3}{4}\implies \theta \approx 0.73752$$
$$\implies L\approx 19.7313$$

Comment: This model assumes the ladder to be in contact with the corner at all times. But the ladder touches the corner only momentarily.

Comment: This is the length of the longest ladder you can carry horizontally around the corner of the corridor.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$x = {b\over \sin \varphi}$$  $$\ell- x = {a\over \cos \varphi}$$  so $$\boxed{\ell = {b\over \sin \varphi}+ {a\over \cos \varphi}}$$

Now take the derivative of it with respect to $\varphi$

Comment: This model assumes the ladder to be in contact with the corner at all times. But the ladder touches the corner only momentarily.

Comment: So?..............................